# Loading an ImageView from an URL in a widget

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-widget

I'm trying to do a dynamic widget that has an `ImageView`. I'm trying to download an image from an URL using `AsyncTask` and then trying to apply the newly downloaded bitmap on to the `ImageView`, but nothing appears in the widget.

Here's the Java code going on in the widget:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{

private static RemoteViews remoteViews;
private static String thumbnailUrl = "..."; // The image I'd like to show

// Async task for downloading an image and setting it to the ImageView
class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap icon = null;
        try
        {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(bitmap == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Bitmap is null!");
            return;
        }
        remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnailView, bitmap);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] widgetIds)
{
    if(remoteViews == null)
    {
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    }

    new DownloadImageTask().execute(thumbnailUrl);
}

} // End of MyWidget
```

The widget does work, because if I put a static `TextView` there, it shows up. However, this `ImageView` does not. The view's ID is correct, and the URL is valid. The bitmap is not null when `onPostExecute()` is called. Why doesn't the bitmap show up?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing and would really appreciate it if you could post a code sample of how you achieved the desired result.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace the `AsyncTask` with an `IntentService`. There is every possibility that your process will be terminated before you get your work done. Have your `AppWidgetProvider` delegate to the `IntentService`.

Second, use better code for downloading the image than what you have, as it will not deal well with typical mobile issues like sporadic connectivity. There are plenty of image-loading libraries available (Picasso, Universal Image Loader, etc.) that will be more resilient in the face of problems.

Third, you actually have to do something with the `RemoteViews`. Right now, you call `setImageViewBitmap()`... and then drop the `RemoteViews` on the floor. You need to [use `AppWidgetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html) to tell Android to update the app widget with the `RemoteViews`.

And, as Ashish points out, bear in mind that there is a 1MB limit on IPC transactions, which will cap how big your `Bitmap` can be. Many of those image-loading libraries also have resampling logic built in to scale your image to an appropriate size, so you can aim to avoid this limit.

Comment: The image is under 100 kB in size, that shouldn't be a problem. I added calls to the `updateAppWidget()` method to update all the widgets, but nothing still shows up.

Comment: @manabreak: "The image is under 100 kB in size, that shouldn't be a problem" -- if you are measuring that in terms of disk space, that is much too big. That will be several MB uncompressed, and it is the uncompressed size that matters. At 4 bytes/pixel (default `ARGB_8888`), you have fewer than 256K pixels to work with.

Comment: I swapped the image with a 4 kB one (120x90 px), still nothing shows up.

Comment: Actually, now it showed up when I removed the widget and added it again.

Answer (score 0):

check you logcat output, are you getting something like -

> ERROR/JavaBinder(20204): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

If yes, then you are hitting the file size limit :P